# ajax loader in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm using the AjaxToolkit in asp.net project c# code.
I have a script managet and an update pannel in my page. It all works perfect.
The only problem is that I can't figure out how to show the Ajax loader gif while the request is processed.

Any idea?

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se updateprogress of tool kit :hope this will help you

```
<asp:updatepanel id="ResultsUpdatePanel" runat="server">    
<contenttemplate>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <asp:updateprogress id="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" associatedupdatepanelid="ResultsUpdatePanel" dynamiclayout="true">
                        <progresstemplate>

                           <img src="support/images/loading.gif">

                        </progresstemplate>
                    </asp:updateprogress>

                    </div>

 //your control code
</contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use some styles to Div Loader will come at the center of the screen..so it looks good.
use this

```
<div style="text-align:center;position:fixed;left:40%;top:40%;padding-top:10px;">
  <asp:updateprogress id="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" associatedupdatepanelid="ResultsUpdatePanel" dynamiclayout="true">
      <progresstemplate>
         <asp:Image ID="LoaderImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loading.gif" />
      </progresstemplate>
  </asp:updateprogress>
</div>
```